# is there a way to execute system command with given priority?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, thread-priority

I mean this command:

```
system("myprogram.exe");
```

Is there a way to make it run for example in below-normal priority mode ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WINAPI has a function called [`CreateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that allows the specification of a priority:

```
dwCreationFlags [in]

    The flags that control the priority class and the creation of the process.
For a list of values, see Process Creation Flags.

    This parameter also controls the new process's priority class, which
is used to determine the scheduling priorities of the process's threads.
For a list of values, see GetPriorityClass. If none of the priority class
flags is specified, the priority class defaults to NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS
unless the priority class of the creating process is IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS
or BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS. In this case, the child process receives
the default priority class of the calling process.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **SetThreadPriority()** on the main thread of the application

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a fuller answer:

Three different options (these aren't steps):

- During **CreateProcess**, specify the process priority CLASS (individual thread priorities are derived from the process priority class).
- After starting of the application, use **SetPriorityClass**. This lets you change the priority CLASS at will.
- Change individual thread priorities via **SetThreadPriority**. These go up and down in accordance with the 'base' priority CLASS.

For more information, see MSDN.